# In Blender's built in text editor is there a way to read a built in class or function's docstrings?

Tags: python, scripting

I suppose I can just google search the scripting documentation and keep another tab open but can I do this more directly in Blender? Maybe using the python console or directly in the text editor? I also installed the Code Autocomplete addon but I am not sure if it does what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inspecting a python object in the Python Console, press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to Autocomplete.

[image]

If the completion is ambigous, the console will complete the command upto a certain point and offer you the options. If you end with a period, all properties are displayed.

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> on a not completed function (where the closing bracket or more is missing) will print a docstring if available.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I am going to mark this as the correct answer.